# phpmyadmin in linux installation

Tags: linux, software-installation

I am trying to install **Request Tracker** tool in my **RHEL 5.6** machine.I am following the instructions as mentioned in [this](http://howtoconfigure.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-install-request-tracker-40x-in.html#chitika_close_button) link. However, I am facing couple of issues.

The first issue is in the below step. I have some dependency issues for php files.

```
# yum install  rpm* nmap expect vsftpd net-snmp* ntp* subversion subversion-devel 
mysql mysql-server mysql-devel screen perl-Crypt- PasswdMD5 graphviz php-xml 
php-cli php-mhash php-ldap php-devel php-pdo php-imap php-readline 
php-ncurses php-soap php-snmp php-common php-mcrypt php-odbc php-mbstring 
php-gd php-bcmath php php-xmlrpc php-pear php-mysql php-dba mod_perl-devel 
mod_auth_mysql mod_perl mod_authz_ldap gd gd-devel gd-progs gcc* 
-- exclude=gcc-java* -- exclude=gcc4-java phpmyadmin mod_fcgid perl-GD 
perl-GnuPG-Interface perl-GraphViz perl-YAM
```

So, I tried to do the below command.

```
yum install php
```

When I do the above command, I received the below message.

```
Package matching php-5.1.6-40.el5_9.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

So, as per the tutorial link, I needed **phpmyadmin**. So, I used the below command.

It gave me the below output.

```
Error: Missing Dependency: php-api = 20041225 is needed by package php-mcrypt-5.1.6-5.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-40.el5_9 is needed by package php-gd-5.1.6-40.el5_9.i386 (rhel-i386-server-5)
```

If I try to install the missing dependencies, **php-common** using yum command, I receive the below message.

```
Package matching php-common-5.1.6-40.el5_9.i386 already installed. Checking for update.
```

If I try to install the missing dependency, **php-api** using yum command, I receive the below message.

```
php53-common-5.3.3-21.el5.i386 from rhel-i386-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
```

How can I install the phpmyadmin so that I can continue with the installation of Request tracker tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this thread, it appears to be the same issue you're running into. The thread is titled: [CentOS 6.0, php-mcrypt](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=41463). I realize this thread is discussing CentOS 6, and you're using 5.6, but the issue is still the same.

To resolve this you'll need to add the [Remi RPM repository](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) and then install the php55 packages from there. This should clear up your issue.

*php55-mcrypt*

- [EL5 - i386](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/i386/repoview/php-mcrypt.html)
- [EL5 - x86_64](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/x86_64/repoview/php-mcrypt.html)

Use the appropriate PHP packages from this repository instead!